# Setting html-attributes to HTML forms using serializer in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to make page with form that contains any kinds of inputs. I'm using Django and rest framework. I've succeded in representing HTML form using rest framework {% render_form %} tag and serializer with some fields. But i'm just able to set few attributes, for instance, placeholder and input_type. And it works well. The next thing I want is setting some #id, .class and any attributes to input tags(or select) on a server side because I need to handle these HTML forms using knockoutjs or JQuery but I can't do it without data-bindings or #IDs. I couldn't find any information about it. I guess it is possible to set any attributes to inputs on client-side finding them by label name but it seems a bad way. Or maybe I could get list of fields and just represent it in html template? Are there some pieces of advice?

Comment: Don't know much about Django rest, but take a look at Django [widget attributes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs).

Comment: Yeah. Thank you. It's a good solution.